# How to convert PDF to Google Docs for several files, to save space

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, pdf

I'm trying to save space on my Google Drive. I noticed I have several PDFs stored, most of which are over 1MB. According to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2407404), Google Drive can convert PDFs to Google Docs (which is nice as it doesn't count against storage space).

What's the best way to do this given that several PDFs have already been uploaded to Google Drive?

The manual way would be to download them all, upload and convert them, then delete the PDF versions.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have a look at this http://googledrive.in30minutes.com/how-to-convert-pdf-to-word-or-google-docs/ whether this helps.

Comment: @Vembu it half helps...I would have to go through each on manually and move it to the correct folder. BTW, is there a way I can find the location of a file in google drive (for example which folder it is contained in)?

Comment: Check this [Full Path to Files in Google Drive](http://ignew.com/2014/06/04/finding-file-locations-in-google-drive/).